# Why are favorites in Windows 7 Internet Explorer 8 the start menu All Programs links?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, favorites

When I open my favorites in IE8 on Win7 64 bit, all the folders and programs from Start Menu -> All Programs are listed - why? And is there a way to fix this?

I don't really want or need to open up programs from here.

---

I was not able to find my favourites folder,, so in IE I added a new folder called "yyyyyyyyyyyy" and then I searched for it on C drive - I found it here:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

I also went to Start Menu -> All Programs and there it was too.

So, it appears that it is mapping the favorites in IE to the start menu, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your favourites folder (It's inside your profile in the User folder on your hard drive.)

Make sure the only things in there are actual favourites and not a shortcut or similar to other folders, like say... the Start Menu.